# Pass Javascript value in php onclick

Tags: php, javascript

The below is the PHP code in which i need to get the value of input-text onblur.

```
echo $script = "<script>";
$q = "select * from sp_documentocompra_detalle where dcd_codigo
='<script>document.getElementById('busqueda_de_producto').value;</script>'";
$res = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo $script .= $row."</script>";
```

The below is the HTML code that includes the input-text.

```
<input type='text' name='busqueda_de_producto' id='busqueda_de_producto' value='' onclick="text();"/>
```

Comment: it should be *$row['someindex']."</script>";*

Comment: the simplest way is use `$.post()` or `$.get()` jquery's methods..

Comment: Just use the search. You are not the first one asking this. Just use the search. It is in the right top corner of the site. And if you go below that there is the *Related* column. Just make use of these tools, there is more than just posting a question available on this site. E.g. existing questions with answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your php script and in your view file you can use AJAX to pass value on click.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function text()
    {
        var textVal=$("#busqueda_de_producto").val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type:"POST",
            url:"index.php",  //here goes your php script file where you want to pass value
            data: textVal,
            success:function(response)
            {
               //what to do in case of response
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and for the text input are do something like

```
<input type='text' name='busqueda_de_producto' id='busqueda_de_producto' value='' onclick="javascript:text();"/>
```

Comment: and from the index.php file how could i use the variable in the Javascript

Comment: the value of input file is passed with POST request. Get access to $_POST, there is your value, get it, ensure security, because it is passed from client and work with it.

Comment: This is the php code from where i want $row array
<?php
   $q11 = "select * from sp_documentocompra_detalle where dcd_codigo".$_GET['codigo']; 
   $res11 = mysql_query($q11);
   $row11 = mysql_fetch_array($res11);
?>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Javascript that way to write into your PHP code. In a classical scenario, the PHP source code is compiled and/or interpreted on your server, before the HTML and JS is sent to your client. The Javascript is interpreted within the browser, *after* the interpretation of the PHP code.

You can generate JS code with PHP but not the reverse. Once your Javascript obtains the value it needs, there must be some kind of HTTP request (either by a page load or via the use of a XMLHttpRequest object) in order to build the SQL query (in PHP, probably) and pass it to the server.